# JSON string to UUID format

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a JSON call that returns a UUID "E07ABFD8-429B-4A5A-AEDB-EE4C9E9A7C74" which is a SessionID. I print the JSON so I know it's not blank. I would like to write the SessionID to a CoreData table and field with UUID format.

```
let sessionID = UUID(uuidString: JSON(dictMain)["SESSIONID"].stringValue)!
```

I'm unable to convert the JSON to UUID format to place it in the Core Data, the variable above returns blank.

```
SVProgressHUD.show()
        SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.black)
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        let apiEndpoint: String = "https://xxx.xxx.net/iocserver/MobileApp.aspx?action=MobileApp"
        //CompanyNameDD.selectedIndex
        let headers = HTTPHeaders(["Content-Type" : "application/json","WebSiteAppID":self.PassSiteId])
        var param = [String: Any?]()
        param["Command"] = "ValidateUser"
        var cellNo = KeychainSwift().get("userMobileNumber") == nil ? "" : KeychainSwift().get("userMobileNumber")!//PassMobileNumber
        cellNo.removeFirst()
        let strParam = jsonToString(json: ["CELLNO":"+27\(cellNo)","PIN":self.OTPfield.text!])
        param["Data"] = strParam?.base64Encoded()
        param["Signature"] = strParam?.base64Encoded()?.sha256Signature()
        AF.request(URL(string: apiEndpoint)!, method: .post, parameters: param as Parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                if let json = value as? [String: Any] {
                    print(json)

                    let data = JSON(json)

                    if data["Status"].stringValue == "0" {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: data["Message"].stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .destructive) { _ in
                            return
                        })
                        self.present(alert, animated: true)
                    }
                    else {
                        let jsonStr = data["Data"].stringValue.base64Decoded()

                        let dict = convertToDictionary(text: jsonStr!)

                        if let dictMain = dict {


                            let sessionID = UUID(uuidString: JSON(dictMain)["SESSIONID"].stringValue)!

                            self.manageUserAccount.CreateUserAccount(NameSurname: (JSON(dictMain)["FNAME"].stringValue + " " + JSON(dictMain)["SNAME"].stringValue), CompanyOffice: self.PassCompanyOffice, EmployNo: JSON(dictMain)["EMPNO"].stringValue, CurrencyBalance: self.PassCurrencyBalance, AccountPin: self.OTPfield.text!, SessionID: sessionID, CompanyOfficeID: self.PassSiteId)
                            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .destructive) { _ in
                    return
                })
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
```

Comment: Are you using SwiftyJSON or where does the "JSON" keyword comes from?

Comment: Correct, I'm using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Comment: Usually you don‘t want to use stringvalue when accessing a swifty jspn dict but rather string and check and guard against that, but I‘m not sure that is the issue. Check if there‘s a difference between .string and .stringvalue.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns blank"? `sessionID` is not an optional, so it either crashes or some UUID is stored into it.

Comment: When in debug mode I can view the value dictMain and can see that the JSON SessionID has "E07ABFD8-429B-4A5A-AEDB-EE4C9E9A7C74" but the above sessionID variable I create is nil.

I need to convert that JSON(dictMain)["SESSIONID"] value to UUID to allow it to be saved in the Cord Data UUID field I created

Comment: Can you post how you `dictMain` is assembled?

Comment: I've added my code to the question

Comment: You are misusing SwiftyJSON heavily. I also don't understand why you get data from the JSON, decode it and then again convert it to a dictionary just to again parse it as JSON. This all doesn't makes and my best advice is to familiarize yourself with how JSON works and how to work with SwiftyJSON. No offense, really, but the code in general is kind of messy.

Comment: Before I pass the JSON I encrypt it with a signature for security. No offense taken, I'm new to JSON.

Comment: Ah, I see, then you should definetely print out `jsonStr` and see if it is valid JSON.